# Insert a PDF file as an object in PowerPoint

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, embedding

I am trying to follow the instructions from [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-pdf-file-content-into-a-powerpoint-presentation-5e7719d5-508c-4c07-a3d4-68123c373a62) to embed a PDF into a PowerPoint slide, but I get the below error message:

[image]

> The server application, source file, or item can't be found, or returned an unknown error. You may need to reinstall the server application.

I tried following the instructions on [this page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint-error-the-server-application-source/8a760aff-f412-4650-bf87-fada8b3d7a77) to disable all the protections to no avail. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when 64-bit PowerPoint can't call 32-bit PDF handler
such as Acrobat Reader.

In such a case, change your PDF handler to a 64-bit product,
or install 32-bit Office.

Comment: how can I check whether the PDf handler is 32-bit or 64-bit? How to check which software is the PDF handler?

Comment: Just double-click any PDF in Explorer. Whatever program comes up is the handler.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Reader is the default application and I believe it is 64bit. Is there a way to check what PDf handler the Microsoft Office/PowerPoint is using?

Comment: Should be the same handler. Are you sure about Acrobat? When I insert a Foxit Reader object (my PDF handler) which is 32-bit I get exactly the same error as you. When I insert an Adobe object it's very slow but works.

Comment: how do you choose to import an Adobe object? 

Comment: This is done in the Insert pane, Text group, Object icon. For me it's called "Adobe Acrobat Security Settings Document".

Comment: Double click a PDF file and if it appears in Acrobat Reader, choose Help | About ... the resulting pane will tell you whether it's 32- or 64-bit Reader.